# Getting Wildfly 8.2.0 final - Undertow "UT010019: Response already commited" error using Java, Spring, Jsp, Extjs

Tags: java, jsp, wildfly, extjs6, undertow

I have a Java Web App that serve two different Extjs single page applications:

- a login app
- the main app

Routing is provided by JSP which redirect to the correct extjs application after login success.
I am aware of [this Undertow's issue](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/UNDERTOW-577) but I am receiving the following error only for a single specific user and not every time. Other users can login without any problems. 
Thanks in advance guys.

```
2017-04-20 09:05:53,877 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-1) UT005023: Exception handling request to /myApp/loginWsController/app: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: UT010019: Response already commited
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:965) [spring-webmvc-3.2.14.RELEASE.jar:3.2.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:844) [spring-webmvc-3.2.14.RELEASE.jar:3.2.14.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829) [spring-webmvc-3.2.14.RELEASE.jar:3.2.14.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at eu.archivagroup.common.filters.EnableCrossDomainFilter.doFilter(EnableCrossDomainFilter.java:36) [archiva-common-web-2.1.0.jar:]
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:101) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343) [spring-web-3.2.14.RELEASE.jar:3.2.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260) [spring-web-3.2.14.RELEASE.jar:3.2.14.RELEASE]
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:63) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:247) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:166) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:197) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:759) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: UT010019: Response already commited
at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.include(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:285) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:229) [spring-webmvc-3.2.14.RELEASE.jar:3.2.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:264) [spring-webmvc-3.2.14.RELEASE.jar:3.2.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1216) [spring-webmvc-3.2.14.RELEASE.jar:3.2.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1001) [spring-webmvc-3.2.14.RELEASE.jar:3.2.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945) [spring-webmvc-3.2.14.RELEASE.jar:3.2.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:867) [spring-webmvc-3.2.14.RELEASE.jar:3.2.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953) [spring-webmvc-3.2.14.RELEASE.jar:3.2.14.RELEASE]
... 58 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: UT010019: Response already commited
at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl.sendRedirect(HttpServletResponseImpl.java:173) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendRedirect(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:176) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at org.springframework.security.web.firewall.FirewalledResponse.sendRedirect(FirewalledResponse.java:25) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendRedirect(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:176) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SaveContextOnUpdateOrErrorResponseWrapper.sendRedirect(SaveContextOnUpdateOrErrorResponseWrapper.java:74) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.apache.jsp.pages.login_jsp._jspService(login_jsp.java:75)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:69) [jastow-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:366) [jastow-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:326) [jastow-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:259) [jastow-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:82) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchToServlet(ServletInitialHandler.java:198) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.include(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:279) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
... 65 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems came from simultaneous access of different users with the same credentials, plus the Undertow's issue.
Upgrading to a newer version of Wildfly solved our problem.